# laravel handle request uri at a single place

Tags: laravel, request, handler

I would like to know that what is the best place to handle all request uri. For example:

```
www.abc.com/event1/vote
www.abc.com/event2/vote
```

Now in the above example, i want to process different business logic on the basis of second parameter of the URL (Like event1, event2 etc.) as this parameter is a dynamic parameter. I know that i can use before_filter in the controller, but i want to execute my logic before any controller execution at a single place. i dont want to write before_filter in each controller.

Comment: why not put all them in a group in route file and execute the logic in group filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a global `before` event that will fire on every request before any/every route gets handled:

```php
App::before(function($request) {
    // dd($request->all()); // All inputs
    // dd($request->input()); // All inputs
    // dd($request->segments());  // All segments as an array
    // dd($request->segment(1)); // event1
    // dd($request->url()); // www.abc.com/event2/vote
});
```

Try this approach and check each commented line one at a time and you'll get the idea. Check more about [Application Events](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events) on `Laravel` website.

In this `event` you may access the `Request` object as `$request` and can extract the parts of the `URI` in so many ways, so depending on the part of the `URI` you can make decisions. For example, to get the segment `1` you may do something like this:

```php
// www.abc.com/event2/vote
$event = $request->segment(1); // event2
if($event == 'event2') { ... }
```

*You may declare this event in your `filters.php` file.*

Comment: Thanks WereWolf - The Alpha !! It works for me. However, i would like to know that how can i call a method of any controller here. Actually, i have to write some logic (Preferably in a Controller) on the basis of coming URI because the in my example event1 or event2 would be the name of the event and i have to fetch their id from the database. Therefore, i want to write logic where i will have the access to the database/models etc. But in app/filters.php i am not sure if i can have access to database.

Comment: To call a method of a controller you may use `App::make('controllerName')->methodName($parameters)`.